# How to send keyboard keys to nested input in ion-input using protractor

Tags: ionic-framework, protractor

Hi I am having a problem trying to send keystrokes to an ion-input in an ionic application.

I can successfully click the ion-input but when i try to send keys it says

> Failed: unknown error: cannot focus element

I think protractor is binding to the ion-input and not the nested input element in the html.

**my pseudo code implementation**

```
emailInput = element(by.css('.passwordInput'));
emailInput.click();
emailInput.sendKeys("test@tester.com"); //error here
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to it .

So when looking at the chrome developer console i noticed i was trying to send keys to the ion-input instead of the nested input element:

```
<ion-input class="emailInput" ...>
    <input class="text-input" ...>
    </input>
</ion-input>
```

so all i had to do was point to the element that has ".emailInput" and a ".textInput" so i have this now in the page object:

```
getEmailInput() {
return element(by.css('.emailInput .text-input')).getWebElement();
}
```

That solved it and now I can send keys to the input box.